# Simple Java EE client desktop application and web with MySQL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, orm, web

At start i have to say that im totaly new to java ee and quite new in java at all. I have to do my study project with this one. First of all i need a standard desktop aplication that connects with the remote mysql database. The second one less important is web aplication that connects with database too. The question is how the flow of informations should look like according to java ee standards ?
Something like client aplication > remote > java beans > local > mysql ?
What api's do you recomend with this simple project to take care of ORM etc. ?
And the last one i need some tutorials or books about java ee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually give too few requirements and constraints, even to choose a technology stack.

What i can advise according to your post :

Try to factorize the data access layer (DAOs) as you will probably share it between desktop and web application. For this you have 2 solution :

**Solution 1** : jar module embedded in both application:
This imply that the component have to be also runnable outside of a server container (Java SE). I would so advise not to use Java EE but Spring as Java EE does not yet provide a standalone "lightweight" container properly managing persistence context.

Spring will allow you to define a data access component with a datasource (plugged to remote DB) and container transaction management (using an ORM outside of a container isn't very interesting imho) which will run alone (desktop app) and inside any servlet container  (tomcat, etc) (web app) with for only difference a configuration file.

It will give:

**Standalone** : client [Swing views > controllers > Spring managed DAOs] > remote database
**web** :  client [html] > web server [any view techno (spring mvc for example) > Spring managed DAOs] > remote or local database

**Solution 2** : SOA architecture with a shared data access component instance deployed on the web server and exposed to standalone app through web-services :

**standalone** : client [swing views > controllers] > http > web or Java EE server [REST or SOAP web-services > DAOs] > local or remote database

**web** :

client [html] > web server [any view techno > DAOs] > local or remote database

client [RIA (Ajax, Flex, etc...)] > web server [REST web services > DAOs] > local or remote database

Otherwise i would advise not to use an ORM if you don't really need it cause the learning curve is quite long compared to advantage it will bring to you. (Ofc it depends of your context and requirement : complexity of the data model, existing DB or new one, DB exclusively used by your app or shared, existing stored procedure or trigger, high concurrency, etc, etc)

Answer (score -1):

For the desktop application I would describe the flow as this:
Java Application(Core Java) -> EJB (Enterprise Java Beans) -> Hibernate (ORM) -> MySQL (DB)

For the web application:
Struts (Front end framework) -> Hibernate -> MySQL

You could also use EJBs in between struts and Hibernate. If the projects are related, you actually just need to swap the front end really  (The Java App and the Struts component).

I wouldn't jump right into piles of frameworks right away. I learned much better starting with JSPs and Servlets, then progressing into Struts, then learning Hibernate, etc. Its too much to worry about all at once.

I don't have books to recommend, but http://www.mkyong.com/ has some decent examples.

Comment: EJB for desktop app ??? Could you please explain me how you will run EJB outside of a Java EE container ?